# Custom proxy copying PDF

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdf, servlets

I am writing a custom proxy as a web service client for our main application, which uses REST web services. For security reasons, I am trying to use a servlet on the client side as a proxy to retrieve a PDF from the server side and then display that in the application web browser through the client app.

As the heart of this, I have this piece of code:

```
  protected void copy(HttpResponse fromResponse, HttpServletResponse toResponse)
      throws IOException{
    HttpEntity entity = fromResponse.getEntity();
    for(Header header:fromResponse.getAllHeaders()){
      toResponse.setHeader(header.getName(), header.getValue());
    }

    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(entity.getContent());
    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(toResponse.getOutputStream());

int oneByte;
int byteCount = 0;
while((oneByte = inputStream.read()) >= 0){
  outputStream.write(oneByte);
  ++byteCount;
}

log.debug("Bytes copied:" + byteCount);
```

which should copy the PDF from the returned output stream to the current output stream and then return it.

When I run it, though, I get an error from Adobe Reader saying the file is damaged and could not be repaired. When I run the URL directly the file is fine, so it has to be something in the handoff. The byteCount is equal to the PDF file size.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I closed outputStream after writing to it and it works fine.

I didn't think you were supposed to do that?

Comment: outputStream.flush() should be enough

Comment: outputStream is a BufferedOutputStream, so you obviously need to flush it's buffer eventually, either explicitly or implicitly by closing.

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
while((inputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0){
  outputStream.write(buffer);
}
```

you will always write the full length of buffer, regardless of its effective content length as write can only look at the buffer's size to determine what to write.

```
int count;
while(((count = inputStream.read(buffer))) >= 0){
  outputStream.write(buffer,0,count);
}
```

should take care of that problem.

Comment: Someone pointed the same thing out to me. I have modified the code and am still having the same issue.